# Importing waypoints from OziExplorer wpt files

Tags: convert, gpsbabel

I do not succeed in importing waypoints from Ozi files (extension .wpt). I tried both converting through GPS-Babel to XML (.gpx) and importing in QGIS with the GPS-tool. Both times set to WGS 84, as is the setting in Ozi.

What should I do?

Comment: Could you describe how the import process fails?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to import from a GPS... You can try [DNRGarmin](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/tools/arcview/extensions/DNRGarmin/DNRGarmin.html)! It takes several files (.gpx, .kml, shp, txt, etc) and can convert them to .shp files.
Hope that helps.

Comment: While very capable and a mainstay of GPS users for many years, DNR Garmin (now [DNRGPS](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/DNRGPS/DNRGPS.html)) doesn't know how to handle Oziexplorer files. _However_ [tag:gpsbabel] which is bundled with DNRGPS does. Get to it from _File >> Launch GPSBabel_ menu. (but OP already said GPS babel doesn't work on their files)

Answer (score 1):

**Global Mapper will convert WPT to SHP**

OziExplorer Waypoint (WPT), Route (RTE), and Track (PLT) Files

Description:
The OziExplorer waypoint (WPT), route (RTE), and track (PLT) file formats are used to store user waypoints, routes, and track logs from GPS devices by the OziExplorer application. The WPT and TRK files can be loaded into Global Mapper v6.00 and above, and the RTE files can be loaded into v9.01 and above.

http://www.globalmapper.com/product/formats_vector.htm#OziExplorer_Waypoint_WPT,_Route_RTE,_and_Track_PLT_Files

ESRI Shapefiles

http://www.globalmapper.com/product/formats_vector.htm#ESRI_Shapefiles

http://www.globalmapper.com/product/formats.htm
you can use a trial version to test it.

Answer (score 1):

**[gpsbabel](/questions/tagged/gpsbabel)** is very capable, and used under the hood by many programs. It can be hard to sort out just what options to use even with the gui that's now included. I suspect for the original poster an incorrect combination of parameters was being passed, though we can't rule out internal file data corruption.

In any case, at this point you need to go to the source and use GPS Babel directly, to get a more direct view of what is going on and possible error messages.

**Step 1: use a tool to help determine the right combination of command line options**.

I like the online free [GPS Vizualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/gpsbabel/) service. What I particularly like about gps-viz, aside from being available without installing and instant viewing gratification, is that it shows the command line used to use as templates in your own scripts.

[image: GPS Vizualiser conversion dialog]

> The following GPSBabel command was executed:
>   `gpsbabel -w -r -t -i ozi -f "2011 track.plt" -o gpx -F "2011 track.gpx"`

**Step 2: use the command line to inspect error messages directly**

In the event the problem was unresolved in Step 1, use the command line from it in your own local console. Prepend `-D n` to increase the verbosity of debugging messages, with 0 meaning none. The debugging info is format specific (some don't add very much extra detail). The following is level 3:

```
gpsbabel -D 3 -w -r -t -i ozi -f "2011 track.plt" -o gpx -F "2011 track.gpx"
GPSBabel Version: 1.4.4
options: module/option=value: ozi/snlen="32" (=default)
options: module/option=value: ozi/wptfgcolor="black" (=default)
options: module/option=value: ozi/wptbgcolor="yellow" (=default)
options: module/option=value: ozi/proximity="0" (=default)
options: module/option=value: ozi/altunit="feet" (=default)
options: module/option=value: ozi/proxunit="miles" (=default)
cet_util: Converting from "US-ASCII" to "UTF-8", done.
options: module/option=value: gpx/snlen="32" (=default)
```

**Step 3: follow up on errors**

Follow up on the error messages, with many round trips to [the fine manual](https://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.5.0/index.html), and questions here on GIS Stack Exchange as needed. The more research and info you put into your questions the better and faster results (low effort on this question meant 3.5 years before an effort-ful answer).